# Interaction energy of two brownian spherical particle in liquid

Tags: energy, interactions, brownian-motion

Let us consider two hard sphere in finite volume. Their motion is Brownian. What can we say about interaction energy? Is it less then $kT$?

I know that we can describe this system by Langevin equation. Of course, the process of interaction hard to describe because each of particles creates elastic waves, so we need to use acoustic equations. But I don't understand how I can estimate interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After immersion each of particles get maximum $\frac{3}{2}kT$. So, they can interact with $3kT$ maximum.

Comment: Thank you! So, this problem maybe does not have any sense...